# What is the best algorithm to calculate number of not black pixels in the closed area?

Tags: c#, algorithm

What is the best c# algorithm to calculate number of not black pixels in the closed area?
I have for example this image. I click the mouse in the red button position. I would like to know how much not black pixels (in this example white pixels) are in the closed area (The square and rectangle should not be calculated)?

[image: pixel count]

Comment: Define an "area". Is it fixed? Why shouldn't the square and triangle not be calculated?

Comment: You could use a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm and count the pixels

Answer (score 1):

You will need emguCV/C# to find a contour(blob) in your image. A function provided by that library that allow you to get all the contours on your image:

```
var contours = YourImage.FindContours(CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL);
```

Then, you will need to build your own algorithm to check which contour does your mouse coordinates fall in. Your sample image, has only three contours (Square, Rectangle and the rest). You will need to iterate those three and test your mouse coordinates against each of their coordinates taking into consideration their area, shape.. etc.

Comment: While he did ask for 'best', which is subjective, this would be major overkill for the simple question as presented.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon I think that to find the largest contour of an image is pretty simple with EmguCV.

Comment: His question did not ask about contours or finding the largest. It asks how many pixels are in a selected region. Many classical algorithms can be implemented that do not require a wrapper to a native CV library, or thinking about it from a CV perspective at all.

Comment: Maybe wrap that in an answer and suggest another solution?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is very similar to a fill algorithm, the only difference is that instead of changing pixel colours you will count them. Search for an implementation of a fill algorithm.

Comment: This is definitely the right approach. Only thing to watch out for is that many fill algorithms allow pixels to be 'touched' multiple times, which would not be okay in counting.